# UITableView with custom cell subview - respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: uitableview

I have a ViewController that contains a UITableView in which the cells are created via a custom subview (so that each cell will have a label and textfield).  The subview includes TextField delegate methods that get fired on textFieldDidBeginEditing, textFieldDidEndEditing, etc.  The UITableView caches the cells that are visible and destroys them when a cell is no longer visible.  The problem I have is when the user taps on a TextField in a cell and then scrolls the table so that the cell being "edited" is out of view and then taps on a new cell to edit it, the original cell's textFieldDidEndEditing delegate method is called, causing a "respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance" error because the original/first TextField has been destroyed by the UITableView when it was scrolled out of the visible area.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before and found a solution so that I can keep my textFieldDidEndEditing methods for proper handing of the data the user's input without having the now-invisible cells destroyed?

EDIT: I just found this in the UITableView Class Reference doc: "Avoid relayout of content. When reusing cells with custom subviews, refrain from laying out those subviews each time the table view requests a cell. Lay out the subviews once, when the cell is created."

This is, I think, the root of my issue.  But I am not sure how to follow this advice.  Help...

Comment: Did you find a solution to this eventually?

Comment: I found out that in my case, simply not having the reuse identifier specified in the nib was causing deallocation of the cell, ios6 was forgiving of this, but ios7 not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The UITableView caches the cells that are visible and destroys them when a cell is no longer visible." That's true only if you don't provide a reuse identifier.

Assuming that you're working on a detail view where each cell is presenting (conceptually at least) a property of some model object, you can assign each cell a unique reuse identifier. You can set this directly in Interface Builder, or, if you're creating the cells programmatically, by passing it as an argument to `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` or `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier`.

Given a reuse identifier, the table view will cache the cells for its entire lifetime. To get a cell from the cache use

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Some Identifier You Made Up"];
```

Again, use different identifiers to distinguish unique cells, if necessary.

An alternative for a detail view that has a fixed number of unique cells is to store a reference to each cell in an instance variable (or store the whole group of them in a collection). As long as you retain the instance variables, the cells won't be deallocated even if you didn't bother providing reuse identifiers.

Comment: In hindsight, I think my "EDIT:" actually muddied the water here... after trying several things, I don't think this issue has anything to do with reusing cells by an identifier.  It has everything to do with a cell being released when it goes off the screen.  You see, at that point, there is still the TextField delegate method "textFieldDidEndEditing" that is going to get called when the user taps on a different cell (with a different instance of a TextField in it... but the original instance of the TextField has been released, causing the error.  Any advice?

Comment: I hadn't seen your edit before posting, so I was addressing your original question. If you want me to more specific, I'd need to see your code.

Comment: I appreciate that jlehr.  Unfortunately, in this case I would have to post so much code that my company would have a complete fit.  I am going to see if I can create a new test app that I can repro the issue on and if I can I will post that for you to inspect.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I don't need to see your code, but I'm wondering whether you actually understood my post. If follow either of my suggestions, the cells and their contents won't be deallocated, and you won't have the problem you've described. Have you tried that? So far you've provided no details whatsoever, so I had to guess whether you're presenting a list view or a detail view. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Im wondering if this could be your issue:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    // dont do this -->cell = [[[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


    NSArray *topLevelsObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewUserCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelsObjects){
        if ([currentObject  isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell = (customCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found a solution yet. But I faced the same problem, and I fixed it by setting the delegate of the textfield to nil in dealloc of my custom field, before releasing it. This way the delegate textFieldDidEndEditing is not called on the deallocated cell.
I was also not using a reuse-identifier.

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [textField_ setDelegate:nil];
  [textField_ release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```